# Emails sent through smtp server is not received to educational domain accounts

Tags: smtp, gmail, flask-mail

I am trying to send email using flask_mail that has configuration as:
MAIL_SERVER = "smtp.gmail.com"
MAIL_USERNAME = "dummy@gmail.com"

username is my personal verified gmail account.
The smtp server is able to send emails to @gmail and @xyz.edu accounts as I see no error.
But I cannot see emails in  @xyz.edu accounts.
I can see the emails sent to my other @gmail accounts.

I am not sure why I cannot see the emails sent by smtp to my @xyz.edu account.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This doesn't look like a programming question, so it's off-topic here. That said, check the receiving side's spam folder, get on the google postmaster tools list, run your email through spamassassin, etc. If nothing helps there are companies that specialize in email delivery services, like https://postmastery.com that you can hire.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't telnet from the exchange box to that specific IP/SMTP then the problem could be on their end or on the path to their end.

> The problem was with the ISP on the other end.

They need to configure

> Exchange to accept mail for multiple authoritative domains.